# How to pass parseInt array to previous array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, string-parsing

I've been asked to read a file and take the text in there and convert them to a 2d array. Since Eclipse is a pain and wont open/read my text file, I made a test in the class that uses an individually initialized 2d array. My problem is that I don't know to put the parseInt'ed array back into the new one. Or how to use that to form a new 2d array. Here's my code: 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String[][] tester = new String[][] { { "-1 2 3 0" }, { "-1 3 4 0" }, { "-1 3 -4 0" }, { "-1 -3 4 0" } };

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int[][] formula = new int[4][];

    while (count < 4) {
        String temp = tester[row][col];
        String[] charArray = temp.split("\\s+");
        int[] line = new int[charArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            String numAsStr = charArray[i];
            line[i] = Integer.parseInt(numAsStr);
            //what to do here??
        }

        row++;
        count++;

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(formula).replace("], ",
     "]\n"));
}
}
```

I want to generate an array that reads like this:

-1 2 3 0

-1 3 4 0

-1 3 -4 0

-1 -3 4 0

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: hi, just do this `formula[count] = line;`

Comment: God, I'm so dense...I can't believe I missed this...Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of `formula` like this:

```
int[][] formula = new int[tester.length][];
```

You want the formula to have the same number of rows as the tester, right?

Also change your `while` loop to loop until `tester.length` instead of a constant 4:

```
while (counter < tester.length)
```

Now, after the `for` loop is where the real business begins:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    String numAsStr = charArray[i];
    line[i] = Integer.parseInt(numAsStr);
}
formula[row] = line; // <------------
```

During the for loop, you've parsed all the integers in one row of the tester. Now it is time to put the row of integers into `formula`, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for that, especially the loop and width conditions!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add items to the array `formula`. Just add `formula[count] = line;` here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        String numAsStr = charArray[i];
        line[i] = Integer.parseInt(numAsStr);
        formula[count] = line;
    }
```

and the output is:

```
[[-1, 2, 3, 0]
[-1, 3, 4, 0]
[-1, 3, -4, 0]
[-1, -3, 4, 0]]
```

Select as answer if it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868369/9251579)
[Java file to 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28257147/9251579)

```
-1 2 3 0
-1 3 4 0
-1 3 -4 0
-1 -3 4 0
```

Demo

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("myFile.txt"); // read file name
        Scanner scan = null;

        int[][] myArray = new int[4][4]; // how many?
        String line = null; // line in .txt
        String[] token = null; // number token

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // loop thru row
                    line = scan.nextLine(); // scan line
                    token = line.split(" ");

                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(token[j]);// loop thru col & parse token int
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        scan.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray)); //fix this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use a List where you could store the arrays and then it's easily convertible into int[][]...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "-1 2 3 0\n-1 3 4 0\n-1 3 -4 0\n-1 -3 4 0";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(test);

        //read
        List<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            arrayList.add(Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray());
        }

        //print
        arrayList.forEach(arr -> {
            Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(item -> System.out.print(item + " "));
            System.out.println();
        });

        //convert
        int[][] matrix = new int[arrayList.size()][];
        matrix = arrayList.toArray(matrix);


        //print
        Arrays.stream(matrix).forEach(arr -> {
            Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(item -> System.out.print(item + " "));
            System.out.println();
        });

    }

}
```

Just beware of the fact that if you have to split it on more then one regex pattern you will have to use a flatmap for each of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

add `formula[row] = line;` **under** the `for` loop